# Splitting strings by multiple characters into separate Lists<>

Tags: c#, list, split

I'm reading in a textfile using `StreamReader` and I need to split the string into separate pieces which will go into their respective Lists.

For example, the string would be the following:

> 'To Kill a Mockingbird 'Harper Lee '978-0061743528 '336

I want to split the string at each occurrence of a space followed by an apostrophe `( ')`, then place each piece into a `List` such as:

```
List<string> BookTitles;
List<string> Author;
List<string> ISBN13;
List<string> Pages;
```

So `"To Kill a Mockingbird"` would become an element of `List<string> BookTitles`, and so on.

I know `String.Split()` splits on a single character, so what other method can I use?

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: It's funny that OP approves but @LaiVung doesn't ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of the [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method that accepts a string array:

```
var input = "'To Kill a Mockingbird 'Harper Lee '978-0061743528 '336";
var items = input.Split(new[] { " '" },StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**Output:**

> 'To Kill a Mockingbird
>
> Harper Lee
>
> 978-0061743528 336

You can assign each entry in `items` to a list of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "'To Kill a Mockingbird 'Harper Lee '978-0061743528 '336";
var values = Regex.Split(input, @"\s'");
```